# Is there any intelligent way of handling VS event handler removal after copy/past of control

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.Net 2008 and have been experiencing event handler removal after I do copy/paste of controls, such as to group box or panels.  I had to add event handles manually for every control. When I try to move them instead of copy/paste, I had to deal with the z-order of each control.  That is also a manual work.  And this all becomes time consuming when there are several of them.

My questions are:

1) Is this a problem only for VS 2008 or for all VS?
2) Is there any other intelligent way of handling this issue?

Comment: The obvious advice applies: design first, code later.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that's the way it is up through VS2013 at least.

If this is a recurring problem with a certain set of controls, you can create a user control containing them and put most of the offending handlers inside the user control.